# How can one tell if a SATA controller is failing?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

Most SATA controller errors exhibit symptoms similar to a hard drive failure, as best as I can tell (read/write errors, operating system stalls, etc.).

I'm having exactly those issues but they appeared near simultaneously across 2 separate hard drives. Moreso, they only happen under high processing workloads (games and the like) and the temperatures for the hard drives never spike above 50 Celsius. Both have the SMART data report "Interface CRC Error Counts" in the thousands and rising. I'd normally suspect the cables or hard drives, but the problems occurred simultaneously.

Is there any tool or way to conclusively know if the hard disk controller on a motherboard is failing?

Comment: to the 'close-voter'… whut? How is this a software-rec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your replaced the cables? From personal experience I had the "Interface CRC Error Count" in the past and a cable change cleared it.

If you do replace it with a known (pref: new) SATA cable and the counter is still active then there is most definitely a controller issues.

Another possibility is to take the hard disk with a new SATA cable into another computer and copy some arbitrary files to it while reading of the respective SMART counter.

Comment: So the Interface error count can't be caused by a hard drive failing on its own (assuming that the controller and cables are OK)? Both hard drives exhibiting the errors have different 'types' of cables (different brands) but I unfortunately do not have any extras to replace them.

Comment: Never mind. I took the computer apart and noticed that the cables routed over the GPU hot air outlet. They were melted into one another.